# Are Donald Knuth's music sheets written in TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, music, knuth

Donald Knuth composed a work for pipe organ “[Fantasia Apocalyptica](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/fant.html)”
He has published the sheets on his website but I was wondering if they were typesetted using T<sub>E</sub>X or some other software (lilypond or something) as I am myself using Plain T<sub>E</sub>X and want to write some music.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because although the words "Knuth" and "TeX" do appear in the question the question is not about properties/behavior/handling of TeX but is about the properties of a sheet of music in pdf. It also seems to implicitly be about Donald E. Knuth's ways of doing things. The question is not in the scope of questions to be asked here. The question should more clearly express the desire of discussing ways of using TeX for writing sheets of music.

Comment: For typesetting music in TeX you could look at [MusiXTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/musixtex). From the manual: _In many cases it will suffice to run tex, but with MusiXTeX 1.15, it is possible to create a file requiring the enhanced capacity of etex. Since etex can handle any file tex can, it’s best always to use etex_.

Comment: In Knuth's book [*Selected Papers on Fun and Games*](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/fg.html), chapters 19 to 22 involve music, and he says in the preface that he "had great fun coaxing METAPOST to typeset the music in those four chapters".

Comment: Oh thank you! I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the document properties of one of the sheet notes pdf, you'll read

```
Sibelius version 7.1.3 on Mac OS X Lion
```

See section **Details** on https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/fant.html

Just tried it on one file: https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/ch3%20-%202019-10-14.pdf , but it's likely there was no change made ;-)

Comment: It's a bit disappointing but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Why disappointing? Latex is not optimized for sheet notation. It's probably included as an image or pdf. So use any other sheet notation software, like free Musescore.

Comment: I thought Knuth might have design his own music font with Metapost and custom TeX macros (I'm not talking about LaTeX btw)

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded one of the pdf files and looked at the properties.

The properties say:

Created by:  Sibelius version 7.1.3 on Mac OS X Lion

Creator: Qt 4.8.0 (C) 2011 Nokia Corporation and/or its subsidiary(-ies)

Sibelius is software for music notation, more information at: https://www.avid.com/de/sibelius

Qt 4.8.0 seems to denote the [Qprinter-object](https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF) of the C++-cross-platform- application development framework [Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/About_Qt), release 4.8. Qt is currently being developed by [The Qt Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Qt_Company), a publicly listed company whereof Nokia is one of the parents, and the [Qt Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Project) under open-source governance, involving individual developers and organizations working to advance Qt.

---

I intend to vote for closing this question because although the words "Knuth" and "TeX" do appear in the question the question seems not to be that much about properties/behavior/handling of TeX but seems to be about the properties of a sheet of music in pdf. It also seems to implicitly be about Donald E. Knuth's ways of doing things. The question seems not to be in the [scope of questions to be asked here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you are interested in ways of using TeX for writing sheets of music, that's a different issue which can be discussed here. The subject and the text of your question should then reflect exactly this desire. :-)